# How to number table with chapter number

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

I inclue and cross-referencing a table in a Rmd file, and I want to add chapter number with the table title and referencing number, like "TABLE 1.1 test", but not "TABLE 1 test". I render the file using bookdown::word_document2. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
title: test
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: yes
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
```
# Heading 1
I'm cross-referencing a table table:\@ref(tab:test).

```{r test}
test <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = 2:7)
kable(test, caption = "test")
```
````

[image: output]

Rmarkdown/Bookdown is really an amazing tool @Yihui, thanks!

Comment: And... What are you asking?

Comment: You could try pandoc-crossref https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref with the chapter option

Comment: I want to add chapter number with the table title like "TABLE 1.1 test", but not "TABLE 1 test" @ABusyProgrammer

Comment: Thank you @scoa. Pandoc-crossref can add chapter number in table title, but hyperlink is disable in docx. I have contact the author.

Comment: It is a known issue in bookdown: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/a5ad84c8/R/word.R#L12-L13 It may change in the future, but currently we only support Pandoc 1.17.2, and I don't think it supports numbered sections in Word.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. As scoa mentioned, I tried Pandoc-crossref yestoday. I can add chapter number in table title, like table 1.1 in both .docx file and .odt file. But as spans and divs are not converted to docx bookmarks by Pandoc, hyperlink to table title is disabled.  [https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/issues/105](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref/issues/105)

Comment: I have [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254248/why-figure-numbers-with-two-digits-separated-by-dot-are-shown-only-in-html-docum?s=2|0.0000) with figures. Do you have any news, @YihuiXie? Do we have any simple workaround?

Comment: @YihuiXie , I found interesting [github repo](https://github.com/KeachMurakami/fudukue/blob/master/demo/cross-reference/demo_crossref.Rmd) with possible workaround. Could you please implement such in bookdown directly?