# Why figure numbers with two digits separated by dot are shown only in html_document2?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Here is simple RMarkdown document with two sections and two images.

```
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

\newpage

# Part 1

Part 1 starts here. See Figure \@ref(fig:fig1-1) 

![(\#fig:fig1-1) expected to be Figure 1.1.](/usr/lib/rstudio/www/images/rstudio.png)

# Part 2

Part 2 starts here. See Figure \@ref(fig:fig2-1) 

![(\#fig:fig2-1) expected to be Figure 2.1.](/usr/lib/rstudio/www/images/rstudio.png)
```

I expect that two images will render with Knit to the following numbering - first is *Figure 1.1*, second is *Figure 2.1*. But I get this rendering only in `html_document2` (see image below):

[image: knit to html render]

I use latest RStudio 1.1.414 with latest bookdown from Git ([38efc82](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/38efc824b23a53c792a68a7e410cd3975faca47d)).
I have two questions here:

1. Why I don't have *Figure 1.1* and *Figure 2.1* in Word or PDF?
2. How can I get *Figure 1.1* and *Figure 2.1* in Word or PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only address PDF output via LaTeX. By default the LaTeX documentclass `article` is used which uses continuous figure numbering. If your document is so long that it makes sense to number the figures within each top-level section, then you might want to use `report` or `book` instead, e.g.:

```
---
documentclass: book
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---
```

Alternatively you can use some LaTeX package to change the formatting of figure numbers, e.g.:

```
---
header-includes:
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---
```

An alternative would be the `\numberwithin` command from `amsmath` in case you are using that package anyway.

Comment: Thank you! For PDF it works. I'll try to get solution for Word (or wait for solutions here).